# Wise Installer: reading registry entry

Tags: windows-installer, wise

I am using Wise for windows installer 5.0 to make a MSI. 
My doubt is can I read the registry entry from the MSI itself under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE..\uninstall\some_program 2.0. 
This some_program can be of several versions like 1.0 or 2.0 or 3.0 etc.
Can I read "some_program" and store it in a property or somewhere so that I can use it to change the MSI installation GUI screens depending on the existense of this entry in the registry. I do not have access to any wisescript package editor or other softwares. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that other program installed using an MSI? If it is there are other options.

Comment: Hi PhilDW, no the other program is not installed using a MSI. I got some help from this link. http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/creating-launch-condition-based-registry-value . My only concern remains now if I could have read the registry from any version of the program , maybe by using a wildcard instead of the version number. eg HKLM\...\uninstall\some_program*\UninstallString but it seems I can't.

Answer (score 0):

Add a system search. I forget what Wise calls this, but it should be similar and executes when AppSearch fires. I have used Wise in the past and was able to accomplish similar things.